ADF Data Flow columns shift during sink
I have a data flow which pulls from a Data Lake Delta and merges the data with an existing table in our SQL database. Everything behaves normally until the Sink step.
Once I create a pipeline to execute this data flow, the columns shift one place, and the ModifiedBy data shows up under the ModifiedDate header, etc. This also happens in the Sink step if I 'Export top 1000' but NOT if I 'Export current page.'
Expected:

Actual:

I have checked the CSV file for any extra commas in the data, and I can't find any nulls that are being misinterpreted. I have reordered my columns to see if it was a particular one causing issues, but the behavior is consistent.
If anyone has seen this behavior in the past, what am I doing wrong?

Can you provide both sources sample input before joining? and after joining?


ADF Data Flow columns shift during sink

I have also tried with same with my sample data in my ADF and got same CSV with both Export top 1000 Export current page options.
Check that your column mappings in the Sink step are properly defined and match the schema of your target table in the SQL database. Avoid relying on auto-mapping, as it might not map column order or names correctly.

Verify that the data types of the columns. Mismatched data types can sometimes cause unexpected behavior. Make sure that the header row in your CSV file is correctly identified and that there are no extra spaces. Review any transformations applied to the data. Ensure that they are not inadvertently causing the columns to shift.
